# Is HC(=NH)OH a stable compound?

Tags: nomenclature, molecular-structure

The molecule $\ce{HC(=NH)OH}$ has been shown to derive from hydrogen cyanide and water (compound **7**). Is it a stable compound?

[image]

source: Das, T.; Ghule, S.; Vanka, K. Insights Into the Origin of Life: Did It Begin from $\ce{HCN}$ and $\ce{H_2O}$? *ACS Cent. Sci.* **2019**, *5*, 1532–1540. https://doi.org/10.1021/acscentsci.9b00520 (open access).

Comment: It is not that difficult to add an illustration to the question to provide some context of the question (especially if the source in question is an open access publication).

Comment: @GeoffHutchison The initially used SMILES string `C(=N)O` is understood by obabel 3.1.1, [ChemDrawJS](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#) (which assigns to this structure `N=CO`), or [molcalc.org](http://molcalc.org/).  *However* the form now used by @Mihoron of `HC(=NH)OH` is not understood by said obabel (contrasting to the other programs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are considering the following molecule.

[image: formimidic acid structure and name]

As stated in the referenced study:

> Values have been calculated at the B3LYP-D3/TZVP+COSMO(ε =
> 80.0)//RI-CC2/TZVP+COSMO(ε = 80.0) and the B3LYP-D3/TZVP+ COSMO(ε = 80.0)//RIMP2/TZVP+COSMO(ε = 80.0) (values shown in parentheses) levels of theory in kcal/mol.

Regarding the accuracy of calculations, Becke, A.D.$^1$ (2014) says, "with dispersion interactions in place, the future looks bright," albeit with warnings "we cannot, quite yet forget the basics," "DFT heaven is probably unattainable," and "DFAs, local or nonlocal, will never be exact," and ends with the note "The next fifty (forty-three) years will be as interesting as the first."

However, the study (referred in the question) suggests that many compounds in the suggested mechanism have been observed experimentally:

> The use of the nanoreactor produces as an output many different
> pathways to new species from the starting reactants. In most of the
> pathways, formaldehyde **3**, urea **26**, formaldimine **2**, and
> glycolonitrile **4** were seen to be formed as intermediates. This
> suggests that these species were the key intermediates en route to the
> formation of the target molecules, as has also been noted by
> experimentalists.

Quick (and *even less accurate*) calculations using [MolCalc](https://molcalc.org/) shows $\Delta_f H = \mathrm{-122.76 kJ mol^{-1}}$, a negative value, suggesting it is a (somewhat) stable molecule.

$$
\ce{C(s) + \dfrac{3}{2}H2(g) + \dfrac{1}{2}N_2(g) \xrightarrow{\Delta H \approx -122.76 \mathrm{kJ\ mol^{-1}}} HOCH=NH}
$$

However, I couldn't find any results for "synthesis of formimidic acid" and thus it could be a (somewhat unstable) intermediate. As has been pointed out in other answers, the tautomer (formamide) is more stable*.

[image: formimidic acid formamide equilibrium favoring formamide formation]

*Approximate heats of formation calculated using [MolCalc](https://molcalc.org/).

#### References

1. Axel D. Becke; Perspective: Fifty years of density-functional theory in chemical physics. J. Chem. Phys. 14 May 2014; 140 (18): 18A301. [10.1063/1.4869598](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4869598)

Comment: I wouldn't call anything with B3LYP accurate. DFT isn't accurate in general. But with proper diligence and calibration it provides quite some insight. That being said, local minima on very approximate levels tend to also be local minima on higher levels. So the basic gist still applies.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I was aware that DFT calculations do show 10-20% error, but this is often attributed to ill-consideration of effects such as solvation, intermolecular interactions, conformational aspects, etc. We must remember that some potentials often perform good in specialized circumstances (eg, a potential may be good for haloalkanes but not for ketones); however, computational chemistry is moving towards a "generalized" method. Statistical/classical thermodynamics and quantum mechanics are the guiding principles of computational chemistry and we do rely on those with confidence, don't we?

Comment: In my opinion, B3LYP is (among) the worst offender(s). At least they include some dispersion and some solvent effects. To my knowledge, there still isn't a generally applicable solvent model. To sum it up: if it is right, it's basically happy coincidence of error cancellation.

Comment: I have partially read the paper. It uses a terrible level of theory and old software, too. It doesn't correctly cite all the methods it is actually using. Maybe they produce a full list in the supporting information. I wouldn't be very surprised if you obtain something with a better suited method of calculation.

Comment: I was a bit imprecise. DFT is of course exact. Density functionals, or density functional approximations (DFA) are not exact. There is a wonderful article by Becke about this. The error in the calculations is problematic and it is within their design. A method that isn't accurate will never become accurate. DFAs perform well, or well enough, but that has nothing to do with accuracy. And without calibration, you won't even realise whether a DFA produces garbage. Accurate methods are expensive and I don't see computational chemistry migrating towards those anytime soon.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン [Becke](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4869598) (assuming you are referring to this article) does say "with dispersion interactions in place, the future looks bright" albeit with warnings "we cannot, quite yet forget the basics," "DFT heaven is probably unattainable," and "DFAs, local or nonlocal, will never be exact," and ends with the note "The next fifty (forty-three) years will be as interesting as the first."

Comment: Another point of order: I have down voted this answer. This is due to the fact, that the following statement is incorrect: *These are (very) accurate calculations and shouldn't be underestimated.* I will gladly reverse this, when a more appropriate wording is used.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I hope the current edits do include relevant comments regarding the accuracy of calculations. Sorry for verbatim copying my previous comment, but I thought that it fulfills the purpose quite well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145961/discussion-between-ananta-and-martin-).

Comment: @ananta out of curiosity, the heat of formation that I obtain with MolCalc for `C(=N)O` is $\mathrm{-125.71 kJ mol^{-1}}$.

Comment: @nightcod3r I calculated it again, and I am still getting $\pu{-122.76 kJ mol^{-1}$. I wonder how you calculated it: What was your starting structure? Which browser did you use? Are there any custom settings in MolCalc.

Comment: @ananta, on firefox 113.0.1 (this should not affect, hopefully) just entered the `C(=N)O` SMILES and calculated the properties, which shows "Heat of Formation -125.71 kJ mol-1". I've been looking for settings as well, but could not find any.

Comment: @nightcod3r I entered SMILES and obtained the same value of $\pu{-125.71}$;; apparently, different results are obtained on MolCalc when entering SMILES and drawing the structure (which I did).

Comment: @ananta it should not be relevant for the scope of the question (at the end of the day, it's just an approximation). I've learned that MolCalc uses GAMESS to do the math server-side, and would like to reproduce it in our own system, is $\Delta_f H$ related to any of these magnitudes in this [table](https://www.msg.chem.iastate.edu/gamess/capabilities.html)?

Comment: @nightcod3r I once tried installing GAMESS and it was a nightmare, but it is surely worth another try. The table "summarizes the program's present capabilities for obtaining wavefunctions, applying correlation treatments, and computing derivatives." $\Delta_f H$ is related to all these (whichever combination is used for the calculation). Perhaps, in MolCalc, different combination of settings is used when calculating using SMILES input vs structure input.

Comment: @ananta seems to be related to the G3MP2 method (see [log](http://myweb.liu.edu/~nmatsuna/gamess/tests/exam43.log) for methane, consistent with the $\mathrm{-74.6 kJ mol^{-1}}$ in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane)), but again MolCalc is given a rather different result: $\mathrm{-54.45 kJ mol^{-1}}$.

Comment: @nightcod3r let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146002/discussion-between-ananta-and-nightcod3r).

Answer (score 4):

Compound **7** is the imidic acid of formic acid (hence *formimidic acid*).  However as indicated by $\Delta{}G$, its tautomer formamide **8** is thermodynamically favoured.  Some activation ($\Delta{}G^\#$) has to be invested, though.